Blazor - Javascript Interop calls issue
I am unable to connect to my API service in my .NET Aspire project. From frontend, I have below razor component
.NET Core 8 using Blazor web application (razor.web.js)
Login razor component:
@page "/account/login"

@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))
@inject IAuthenticationService AuthenticationService;

<fieldset disabled="@(expiration is not null)">
    <EditForm Model="this" OnValidSubmit="SubmitAsync" FormName="LoginForm">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="loginModel.Username" id="username" name="username" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="@loginModel.Password" id="password" name="password" required />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
</fieldset>

@if (expiration is not null)
{
    <p>You are logged in until @expiration?.ToLongTimeString()</p>
}

@if (errorMessage is not null)
{
    <p class="error">@errorMessage</p>
}

@code {
    private LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel();
    private DateTime? expiration;
    private string? errorMessage;

    private async Task SubmitAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            expiration = await AuthenticationService.LoginAsync(loginModel);

            errorMessage = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            expiration = null;

            errorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

In LoginAsync method, the line
public async Task<DateTime> LoginAsync(LoginModel model)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    try
    {
        response = await _factory.CreateClient("authservice").PostAsJsonAsync("api/account/signin",
                                                    JsonContent.Create(model, options: JsonSerializerOptions.Default));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
            
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Login failed.");

    var content = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResponse>();

    if (content == null)
        throw new InvalidDataException();

    await _sessionStorageService.SetItemAsync(JWT_KEY, content.JwtToken);
    await _sessionStorageService.SetItemAsync(REFRESH_KEY, content.RefreshToken);

    LoginChange?.Invoke(GetUsername(content.JwtToken));

    return content.Expiration;
}

throws the exception mentioned here:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.'

For a reference, I am using SessionStorage in LoginAsync method but exception is thrown before that line.
I have tried setting prerender to false but nothing is working as expected. I tried examples provided in Microsoft documentation as well as suggestions in forums but nothing seems to be working.
I am unable to understand the root cause of the exception.

I´am not 100% sure, but i think it doesn't matter if you enable or disable prerender. You are still using the InteractiveServerRenderMode and render the page on the server and so you do not have access to the local browser until the page is loaded completely. I do not know, what you are setting in the SessionStorage, but maybe there is a workaround to set the information´s after your get the response for the login and then use the OnAfterRenderAsync hook? Maybe you can provide the whole LoginAsync method as source code to determinate?

could you share your reproducible code with us. and for a now based on the error i would like to suggest you use the OnAfterRender{Async} method to Set Session Storage. .For OnAfterRenderAsync, the component doesn't automatically rerender after the completion of any returned Task to avoid an infinite render loop.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-8.0#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync

@Steinliiippp I have added complete code for LoginAsync method.
